# Error starting a sails app with pm2

Tags: node.js, deployment, sails.js, pm2

I'm trying to start a sails app with pm2, but i got the following error:

```
pm2 start app.js --name myapp -i 2

pm2 logs

[myapp-1 (out) 2014-05-25T13:38:51] info:    Sails              <|
[myapp-1 (out) 2014-05-25T13:38:51] info:    v0.10.0-rc7         |\
[myapp-1 (out) 2014-05-25T13:38:51] info:                       /|.\
[myapp-1 (out) 2014-05-25T13:38:51] info:                      / || \
[myapp-1 (out) 2014-05-25T13:38:51] info:                    ,'  |'  \
[myapp-1 (out) 2014-05-25T13:38:51] info:                 .-'.-==|/_--'
[myapp-1 (out) 2014-05-25T13:38:51] 
[myapp-1 (err) 2014-05-25T13:38:51] debug: Environment : development
[myapp-1 (err) 2014-05-25T13:38:51] debug: Port        : 1338
[myapp-1 (err) 2014-05-25T13:38:51] debug: --------------------------------------------------------
[myapp-1 (err) 2014-05-25T13:38:51] TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'addAsyncListener'
[myapp-1 (err) 2014-05-25T13:38:51]   at Server._listen2 (net.js:1095:18)
[myapp-1 (err) 2014-05-25T13:38:51]   at cb (net.js:1139:10)
[myapp-1 (err) 2014-05-25T13:38:51]   at rr (cluster.js:552:5)
[myapp-1 (err) 2014-05-25T13:38:51]   at Worker.<anonymous> (cluster.js:484:9)
[myapp-1 (err) 2014-05-25T13:38:51]   at process.<anonymous> (cluster.js:611:8)
[myapp-1 (err) 2014-05-25T13:38:51]   at process.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:123:20)
[myapp-1 (err) 2014-05-25T13:38:51]   at handleMessage (child_process.js:318:10)
[myapp-1 (err) 2014-05-25T13:38:51]   at Pipe.channel.onread (child_process.js:346:11)
```

Sails version: `0.10.0-rc7`
pm2 version: `0.8.6`

Also, i don't know how to set the environment and port. I've tried with `--node-args="--prod"` but had no effect.

I've tried with module forever and works fine.

Does anyone have any idea how I could fix this?
Thank you

**Edit**
Apparently is a problem with the version of node.js.
I did some tests and i reported the problem in the pm2 repository: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/491.
Any news i'll update here.

Comment: `--node-args` is for node V8 arguments, not for your script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`--node-args` is for node V8 arguments, not for your script.

If you want to pass CLI arguments to your NodeJS script you must do

`$ pm2 start app.js -- -prod`

Every argument after the `--` will be passed to your script.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the `addAsyncListener` error, but environment variables should work as normal.  I've just confirmed this by test:

> $ NODE_ENV=production pm2 start app.js

In logs:

> [app-1 (out) 2014-05-25T15:27:04] in production environment

Comment: Sure, glad it worked!  Sorry I'm not familiar with sails.js enough to understand what the first problem was.  Hope you get that solved

Answer (score 3):

> Does anyone have any idea how I could fix this?

Start pm2 like this:

```
pm2 start app.json
```

where app.json is:

```
{
  "apps": [{

    "name": "app",
    "script": "/full/path/to/app.js",
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "production"
    }
  }]
}
```

sails: **v.0.11.0**, pm2: **v.0.12.7**